# List all third party packages and theirselves functions used in a Python file

Tags: python

I have many python packages, wrote by my colleagues and I want to write a tool to check which third packages they rely on.

Like this

```
 #it is my package, need to check,call it example.py
 #We have more than one way to import a package, It is a problem need to consider too

 from third_party_packages import third_party_function

 def my_function(arg):
    return third_party_function(arg)
```

and the tool should work like this

```
result = tool(example.py)
#this result should be a dict like this structure
#{"third_party_function":["my_function",]}
#Means "my_function" relies on "third_party_function"
```

I have no idea how to do that, all I can come up implementation of this tool is read a Python file line by one line as string, and use regex to compare it.
Could you give me some advises?

If you don't know what I mean, please comment
 your question, I will fix it as soon as possible.
 Thanks!

Comment: If you have a working environment i.e. all the packages installed in your python installation you can use `pip` like `pip freeze > requirements.pip` to create file `requirements.pip` listing all the packages installed (indirectly the packages need to run your project)

Comment: This is not an easy question to answer.

Comment: Thank for your advise, unfortunately, not all package installed by pip, some packages wrote by ourselves. I need to deal them to.

Comment: Using a line by line search would probably be the best, the alternative I can think of would involve running each script and then checking what's imported to the namespace. But that would likely be more unwieldy and less reliable anyway.

Comment: You could use some recursion and reflection to accomplish this. Use __import__() to dynamically import a Python file which I think exposes things like what other modules it loads. I'm not sure how well that would work with local imports, though.

Comment: Maybe see [How does py2exe decide which modules you need?](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ#How_does_py2exe_decide_which_modules_you_need.3F)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse your files with the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module and check all `Import` and `ImportFrom` statements.

To give you an idea, here's an example:

```
>>> import ast
>>> tree = ast.parse('import a; from b import c')
>>> tree.body
[<_ast.Import object at 0x7f3041263860>, <_ast.ImportFrom object at 0x7f3041262c18>]
>>> tree.body[0].names[0].name
'a'
>>> tree.body[1].module
'b'
>>> tree.body[1].names[0].name
'c'
```

Your script could work like this:

1. Parse the source file via [`ast.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse)
2. Visit each node using [`ast.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.walk)
3. If a node is an `Import` or `ImportFrom` object, then inspect the names and do what you have to do.

Using `ast` is way much easier and more robust than regular expressions or a custom parser.